# Why am I not able to set variables inside a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set variables inside a `foreach()` statement, but it keeps dying.

If I do this, all is fine.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
         echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' . $value['1'] . '">' . $value['1'] . '</a></td>';
         echo '</tr>';
    }
```

But when I do this, it doesn't want to work.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $mls = echo '' . $value['1'] . '';
         echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' $mls '">' $mls '</a></td>';
         echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Syntax wise, I don't see how there's a difference in these statements.  I've also tried `$mls = $value['1'];` and that didn't want to work either.

Comment: echo is a language construct. it does not return a value. `$mls = $value[1]` is all you need.

Comment: Use `(string) $value[1]` if you wanna ensure that it is a string. Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you got a syntax error complaining about the second case, right?  If you say "it keeps dying", you should tell us exactly what happens when something dies.  Even more, *you* should read the syntax error and consider what it says.  The errors are descriptive so that you can figure out what's wrong.

In the second case, you aren't concatenating the strings with the `.` operator.

```
echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' $mls '">' $mls '</a></td>';
```

should be

```
echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' . $mls . '">' . $mls . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: So what do the periods do for the syntax?

Comment: "you aren't concatenating the strings with the . operator" means that the `.` operator concatenates the strings together.  "concatenate" means to join to strings.  "The `.` operator" means that `.` is an operator just like `+` is an operator to perform addition, and `=` is an operator to assign values.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $mls = echo '' . $value['1'] . '';
```

should be

```
$mls =   $value['1'] ;
echo $mls;
```

and

```
  echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' $mls '">' $mls '</a></td>'
```

should be

```
echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=mls&mlsnum=' . $mls . '">' . $mls . '</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code block should look more like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $mls = (string) $value['1'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="http://mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&amp;view=mls&mlsnumamp;=' , $mls , '">'  , $mls , '</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

- When you type `$var = echo "something"` you aren't assigning any values to that variable. Instead you are outputting that string - `echo` has [no return value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).
- You can [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) your variable into a string without appending and prepending empty strings.
- You can use the `,` to echo multiple strings one after another with a [little less overhead](http://www.fusionswift.com/2010/05/php-concatenation-benchmark-comma-vs-period/).
- You should be using HTML entities for your ampersands, even though they are in an attribute's value
- (Finally) You aren't actually concatenating your variable into the third `echo`.